# Cannot instantiate implementation type In .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

i am creating an application in .Net Core. I am getting following exception in Program.cs file as follows

"System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'BotHub.DataAccessLayer.BackgroundDataAccess' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.'"

My Program.cs file as Follows:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureServices((hostcontext, service) =>
                {
                    service.AddHostedService<BackgroundDataAccess>();
                });

    }
```

Comment: `BackgroundDataAccess` should implement interface `IHostedService`. Is that the case?

Comment: It seems like an instantiation of ```BackgroundDataAccess``` fails because it relies on dependency injection but relevant dependencies not configured via ```ConfigureServices```.
Anyway, just turn on "break on any exception" with "debug external sources" options and debug the application to obtain the actual error reason.

Comment: @metacube How to do that

Comment: @VRoxa. How to implement IHostedService in .net core 2.1

Comment: Jetbrains Rider: 1) "View breakpoints and exceptions": "Any exception" -> "Enabled", "Suspend", etc. 2) "Debugger" -> "Enable external source debugging". MS Visual Studio: 1) https://christianfindlay.com/2019/07/14/visual-studio-break-on-all-exceptions/ 2) make sure that "Just my code" is turned off.

Comment: On the application start, the external code tries to activate your hosted service. It looks for a relevant constructor; if it has arguments, the external code tries to substitute an argument from DI container. It is likely the point where the error occurs because needed dependency not configured. Turning external code debugging on will suspend execution on error.

Comment: @Vishvjit shinde An implementation of `IHostedService` must implement a method `StartAsync` and another `StopAsync` as well. `StartAsync` will be called once the `IWebHost` is built. If your `BackgroundDataAccess` needs to set something (the database connection, maybe), then implement the `IHostedService` and make it `IDisposable`, recommended.

Comment: However, it you want your `BackgroundDataService` to be instantiated more than once (lifetime per request, dependency, etc), that means `BackgroundDataService` is not a `IHostedService` but a service to be registered as `services.AddScoped<BackgroundDataService>()`, for instance.